# What should be the approach for form builder plugin for existing web form application?

Tags: database-design, asp.net, webforms

I tried to find an approach to implement form builder plugin but I still not getting any idea how to execute it. I don't get below things.

How can I add dynamic controls to dynamic form with drag and drop functionality. (i.e using jquery or any web form control)
How to store or manage dynamically created form.(database design or any better approach)
Which database is efficient to handle it.I have knowledge of MySQL/maria db/SQL SERVER.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954637/what-should-be-the-approach-for-form-builder-plugin-for-existing-web-form-applic "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: purpose of cross post is just to reach out to more people.

Comment: On Stack Exchange we prefer that you choose the best site, and post your question there.  This isn't CraigsList.

Answer (score 2):

Adding controls dynamically in Webforms is fairly easy

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx

However, you'll need to build a separate drag-and drop system adding fake controls if you want to be able to construct the form client side, as they can only be added server side when the page is constructed. (lets not go into the early webforms AJAX thing as an option)

in terms of storing the form design you have many options, you just need some sort of computer readable document which records the type of control, placement, validation etc. Why not XML?

In practice I've done dynamic forms in webforms many years ago to enable users to design insurance products. I developed a complex system of xpath validation, xml and custom controls. I would not recommend attempting it or any webforms approach in 2017

Additionally the problems with any dynamic form system is that you end up creating a custom programming language which soon becomes as complex as the one your are writing it in.

In practice with that insurance system I ended up creating the forms myself, often having to program a new control type to satisfy the whims of sales people. Even enterprise level things like websphere which promise that business experts can create the system end up requiring developers.

My advice would to be just to program the forms manually as required.

Comment: i really liked your point of 'creating a custom programming language'